# What does 卡了壳 mean?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

Here's the [context](http://cn.tmagazine.com/living/20131218/t18japan/dual/). I am guessing it means "stumble".

> 其他选手则要么在微妙的措辞上卡了壳
>
> Other contestants stumble on delicate phrasing.

But according to [this](http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/544189879.html?qbl=relate_question_0) it means "quiet/silenced"?

> Q: 步枪卡了壳是什么意思？
>
> A: 步枪卡了壳 - 不响 咯咯

Comment: It means a cartridge got jammed inside the rifle, unable to fire off. Metaphorically, it is used by the author to describe words getting stuck in the mouth.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a kind of analogy. Originally, 卡壳 (qiǎ ké) meant "a cartridge got jammed inside the gun."

When people are talking very fast and fluently, they are like a gun continuing shooting without any interruption. Words are "shot" (spoken) fast and continuously. There is also an expression "说话像机关枪一样," the literal meaning of which is that someone "speaks like firing a machine gun."

So when someone gets stuck while speaking, we say that he or she "卡壳".

Answer (score 2):

卡壳 means "getting a stuck cassette" *literally*. *cassette* most probably refer to the one holding bullets in a shotgun. But it's also commonly used to say someone getting stuck in the middle of a speech.

Comment: FYI, we would say "cartridge" rather than "cassette".

Answer (score 0):

I think this word 卡壳了 can also be used in a situation like the following. (not only referring to speech):

> However, for performing the piece, memorizing it HS (=Hand-Separated)
>   will be useful for recovering from **blackouts**,

（“**卡壳了**”, or its noun form 卡壳 is a pretty good translation of "blackouts" here）

(From Fundamentals of Piano Practice PDF Page 107, [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://www.pianopractice.org/book.pdf&ei=durAUprKIor-2gX51oCQAw&usg=AFQjCNE6pWOGnB85hqIYsEc-WiXzOIH5Rw&sig2=R3uVb8OtS_U_7gfSP8ff3Q&bvm=bv.58187178,d.b2I))

Answer (score 0):

it means the round is stuck in the barrel
or sometimes it means your thought is stuck and can't come up with a solution